# PHP Foreach , Where

Tags: php, loops, foreach, where-clause

Is there a way of adding a where class to a foreach equation in PHP.

At the moment I am adding an if to the foreach like this.

```
<?php foreach($themes as $theme){
    if($theme['section'] == 'headcontent'){
       //Something
    }
}?>


<?php foreach($themes as $theme){
    if($theme['section'] == 'main content'){
       //Something
    }
}?>
```

Presumably the PHP has to loop through all results for each of these. Is there are more efficient way of doing this. Something like

`foreach($themes as $theme where $theme['section'] == 'headcontent')`

Can this be done

Comment: You could filter the array before the foreach loop, so first filter for 'headcontent', then loop. But I don't think you gain anything with that.

Comment: Do you run both loops each time? How much code are we talking about in those `if`-statements? And is the content in both cases similar or completely different?

Comment: I don't understand, what are you gonna foreach, when you already reached a certain value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a **`SWITCH`** Statement.

```
 <?php
    foreach($themes as $theme)
      {
        switch($theme['section'])
        {
            case 'headcontent':
                //do something
                break;
            case 'main content':
                //do something
                break;
        }
       }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 17):

A "foreach-where" would be exactly the same as a "foreach-if", because anyway PHP *has* to loop through all items to check for the condition.

You can write it on one line to reflect the "where" spirit:

```
foreach ($themes as $theme) if ($theme['section'] == 'headcontent') {
    // Something
}
```

This becomes really the same as the construct suggested at the end of the question; you can read/understand it the same way.

It does not, however, address the fact that in the question's specific scenario, using any kind of "foreach-where" construction would in effect loop through all items several times. The answer to that lies in regrouping all the tests and corresponding treatments into a single loop.

Comment: This is the perfect answer to my problem, thank you.

Comment: Although my PHP code linter did not like this at all.

Comment: As a syntactic sugar fan, I cannot deny this answer gave me at least some euphoria in the lower abdomen. This should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 0):

You better use `for loop` for that like

```
<?php 
    $cnt = count($themes);
    for($i = 0;$i < $cnt,$themes[$i]['section'] == 'headcontent' ;$i++){

    }
?>
```

Comment: Why? Alternativly use foreach with reference ... gain?

Comment: with reference..??how it will

Comment: Why'd you use a for loop instead? ... `foreach($themes as &$theme)`: Would at least avoid "copying" the array to memory again, and should be nearly as fast as a for loop. But your "way" looks cool also ;) [and as far as I know `===` is faster than `==`]

Answer (score 0):

If someone uses MVC framework ,the answer to "foreach where" is here

```
<?php foreach ($plans as $plan) if ($plan['type'] == 'upgrade'): ?>

    // Your code here

<?php endif; ?>
```

**Remeber** there is no need for the `endforeach;` statement after `endif;`

If someone wants to write more code between `endif;` and `endforeach;` then the above should be:

```
<?php foreach ($plans as $plan): if ($plan['type'] == 'upgrade'): ?>

    // Your code here

<?php endif; ?>

    // More of your code

<?php endforeach; ?>
```